# Convert object returned from server to typescript object

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having trouble converting an object returned from the server to a class I have created in typescript.

My typescript object has all the same properties as the object returned from the server, the only difference is that my property names in my typescript class are camel cased, where the one returned from the server are title cased so when I access something like userModel.isActive in my typescript code, it cannot find this property. Below is the return statement for an api call I am making from my provider.

```
return this.httpClient.post<UserModel>(url, { params: queryParams });
```

I have tried:

```
this.userProvider.getUser(request).subscribe(modelReturnedFromApi => {
    Object.assign(this.myTypeScriptModel, modelReturnedFromApi)
    this.myTypeScriptModel = modelReturnedFromApi
    this.myTypeScriptModel = JSON.stringify(modelReturnedFromApi)
})
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance

Update: It appears that there isn't anything built in that will do what I am wanting so I am going to bite the bullet and just name my properties on my typescript class the same as what is coming back from the server. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: I face that issue before, only way to solve, was to match exact name from response.

Answer (score 0):

if your property names are different you may have to assign each property of `myTypeScriptModel` to the matching `modeReturnedFromApi` property

Comment: they're named identically - theyre just differently cased IE: this.myTypeScriptModel.username
modelReturnedFromApi.Username

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this to copy each title-cased property to the corresponding camel-cased property:

```
for (let p in modelReturnedFromApi)
    myTypeScriptModel[p[0].toLowerCase() + p.substr(1)] = modelReturnedFromApi[p];
```

This only works one level down.  If you have nested title-cased objects that you need to convert to camel case, you'll need a recursive function.  If you have trouble working that out yourself, please add an example input to the question and I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **model** class related to the response that you expect and use its constructor function to convert it into camelCase.

**Person.ts**

```
export class Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  constructor(person){
    this.firstName = person.Firstname;
    this.lastName = person.Lastname;
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  person: Person;

  // mocking response
  response = {
    'Firstname' : 'John',
    'Lastname': 'Wick'
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    // converting response into Person object
    this.person = new Person(this.response);
  }
}
```

[Please refer to this stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grgwd2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)